Some one make a fake token transfer from my friend wallet without having his PK
Now how is that possible? https://etherscan.io/address/0x781C2EA34506d904573E7E92be19154B729B2EE5#tokentxns
this guy send 65 ETH to an address but some scammers sent 65 ETH token(fake) with his address to receiver that the address is vanity of the main receiver address. it's done by a contract.
can you tell me how is that possible please?

Write your own transferFrom function with an owner check for your or your contracts address, airdrop or sell the token, then call the transferFrom function, lots of honey pots do it.
Example, verified so that you can read through it:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x1136c86420775d966be8c294cf808666b568ed57#code
Sent to the address you listed and then pulled from.
Part of the code that is relevant:
@external
def transferFrom(src: address, dst: address, amount: uint256) -> bool:
  # Scam ------------------v
  assert msg.sender == admin,'Only admin can move'
  self.balanceOf[src] = 0 # -= amount
  self.balanceOf[dst] += amount
  # no approvals needed
  #self.allowance[src][msg.sender] -= amount
  log Transfer(src, dst, amount)
  return True

Deployed, transferred then transferred from:

Your friends address:

Note for completeness:
There are even examples in the wild where projects have just forgotten to add the allowance check, and anyone has been able to transfer anyone else's tokens.
When a token gets "transferred" nothing is actually moved, it's just balances being changed in the token contract.
The important distinction is that unlike ETH (or the native coin of an evm chain) which cannot be transferred without the sender signing, contracts will adhere to whatever logic is programmed into them.
If by design the scammer adds a function to wipe a user balance or transfer the tokens away there is no evm level check to stop that.
The function signature is simply the first 4 bytes of keccak256 applied to the function name and types.
So it is easy to create the same signature as a legitimate function yet have a completely different implementation.
The scam in your case seems  like the one attempting to get someone to pick the wrong address from their recently-interacted-with, list.
Say I send you 10 eth for an nft, the scammer hammers out an address with matching characters and then makes it look they sent 10 eth to you.
You don't want to mess up the address so you grab the last one that sent you 10 eth and send them the nft.

Thank you for your explanation, I tested that and it's really working but how they can send multi transfer in only one TX, is it possible? because the safety of ETH will be compromised with this.

How is the safety of eth compromised?
Batch transfer, airdrops, can be done from contract.
